# How to quickly kill java processes in bash?

Tags: bash, kill

On a linux box, I have at most 3 java jars files running. How do I quickly kill all 3 with one command?

Usually I would:

ps ex - get the processes running

then find the process ids then do:

kill -9 #### #### ####

Any way to shorten this process? My eyes hurts from squinting to find the process ids.

My script does the following:

```
nohup ./start-gossip &

nohup ./start &

nohup ./start-admin &
```

Is there a way to get the process ids of each without looking it up?

Comment: "squinting" -- bigger fonts.

Comment: the font is big enough, just too much stuff show up whenever i use "ps ex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the PIDs when you start the processes so you can use them later:

```
nohup ./start-gossip &
START_GOSSIP_PID=$!

nohup ./start &
START_PID=$!

nohup ./start-admin &
START_ADMIN_PID=$!

...

kill -9 $START_GOSSIP_PID
kill -9 $START_PID
kill -9 $START_ADMIN_PID
```

This has the advantage (over `pkill`) of not killing off any other processes that coincidentally have similar names. If you don't want to perform the kill operation from the script itself, but just want to have the PIDs handy, write them to a file (from the script):

```
echo $START_GOSSIP_PID > /some/path/start_gossip.pid
```

Or even just do this when you launch the process, rather than saving the PID to a variable:

```
nohup ./start-gossip &
echo $! > /some/path/start_gossip.pid
```

Comment: indeed. back in 2013, newb programmer. that's what i use now. of course i save my pid to /tmp

Answer (score 18):

Short answer:

```
pkill java
```

This looks up a process (or processes) to kill by name. This will find any other `java` processes too, so be careful. It also accepts `-9`, but you should avoid using `-9` unless something is *really* broken.

EDIT:

Based on updates, you may be able to specify the script names to `pkill` as well (I'm not positive). But, the more traditional way to handle this issue is to leave pid files around. After you start a new process and background it, its pid is available in `$!`. If you write that pid to a file, then it's easy to check if the process is still running and kill just the processes you mean to. There is some chance that the pid will be reused, however.

Comment: this looks good, but i guess i gotta be careful with this since it kills all java..

Comment: If you are unsure, there is a corresponding `pgrep` command that you can use to look for pids first.

Comment: awesome!!! do you this is a way to combine these commands? something like "kill -9 pgrep java"? but then i could just use pkill command.. hmm...

Comment: `pgrep java | xargs kill` but like you said, kind of redundant when you have `pkill`.

Comment: i was really hoping that when i start these jars i can save the process id somehow, the just read it off a txt file or something then kill them off that way.. but pkill is good for now. thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

**To get the process id of that java process run**

netstat -tuplen

**Process ID (PID) of that process whom you want to kill and run**

kill -9 PID